# How to use unicastremoteobject if my class is already extending another class...?

Tags: java, rmi

I have a problem, that my `Server` class is already extending another class. How should I use [`UniCastRemoteObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()`. That will export the object, just like calling super() would if your class extended `UnicastRemoteObject`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an explanation as to why we need to explicity create a registry using LocateRegistry.createRegistry() if we extended UnicastRemoteObject? If we use your method and call UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject() the registry is automatically created and we only need to use LocateRegistry.getRegistry().

Comment: @Prashan That's a new question and nothing to do with this one. You should be starting your own. However, to save trouble, you are completely mistaken. You seem to be deeply confused between what createRegistry() and exportObject() do. I suggest you have another look at the documentation, where you will discover that really they have nothing to do with each other. Exporting your own remote object doesn't create a Registry.